# In c#, Is it possible to pass two different classes as return type from one layer to other layer?

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

My application has n-tier architecture. I have different layers(Business Logic & Data Link & GUI). I am using some common classes to pass data from one layer to the other. I have a class(say `RetrnValueCls`) which has just two variables `Return value` and `Return Message`. While I am passing data from one layer to the other, I need to return this `Return Value` Class along with the other class(say `MasterItemsCls`) which has other variables.

Below are the methods

```
public MasterItemsCls GetMasterItemsMDL()
{
    /* Does some computations and assign them to
    attributes of MasterItemsCls and pass it other methods in other layers. */
}

public ReturnValueCls GetMasterItemsMDL()
{
    /* Does some computations and assign them to
    attributes of ReturnValueCls and pass it other methods in other layers. */
}
```

I want to return both the above classes(`MasterItemsCls` & `ReturnValueCls`) as return type for the method `GetMasterItemsMDL` at once and also I don't want to combine both the classes. Please let me know if there is any way I can do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function can only return a single value, so in that sense the answer is no.

Functions can have `out` parameters, so you could return one of the two values via an `out` parameter.

The cleanest way to handle this in my opinion is to use a third class to contain the other two.  [`Tuple<T1,T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) can be used for that purpose:

```
public Tuple<MasterItemsCls, ReturnValueCls> MyFunction()
{
    // Do stuff
    return new 
    Tuple<MasterItemsCls, ReturnValueCls>(myMasterItemsCls, myReturnValueCls);
}
```

One disadvantage of `Tuple<T1,T2>` is that the values are accessed as the rather unintuitive `Item1` and `Item2`.

If you don't want to use `Tuple<T1,T2>`, it is easy to create your own class to contain `MasterItemsCls` and `ReturnValueCls`.  That is my preferred approach.

Comment: +1 for noting how sometimes unreadable code get, if you use `Tuple`s in C#. For example `tuple.Item1 + tuple.Item2 - tuple.Item3` blows readability away

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: Tuples can be handy, but usually I take the time to create a custom class for that very reason.

Comment: Agree, subjective, but I consider Tuples as a good way of integrating parts written in F# with C# code. F# has a much decent mechanism of dealing with Tuples, like pattern matching. I've tried to incorporate Tuples in a project, but not more than two generic parameters and very-very seldom.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to combine both classes but a possible and direct approach is to generate a class that contains one instance of each class you're trying to return.

```
public class YouClassName
{
     public MasterItemsCls MasterItemsCls {get; set;}
     public ReturnValueCls ReturnValueCls {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method can only return one object. You could possibly create some other class that has instances of each of these others.

Answer (score 0):

Generics may be helpful as a wrapper for your return element.

You could do the following:

```
public ReturnValueCls<MasterItemsCls> GetMasterItemsMDL()
{

}
```

Your `ReturnValueCls<T>` expects a type parameter for its return type.  So your retun type can would act as a wrapper for your desired return and be able to hold your return message.

---

Example of your class definition.  May require some constraints:

```
public class ReturnValueCls<T>
{
    public T Value { et; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}
```